Checking against multiple config with angular-auth-oidc-client
I have an Angular v18 application, using the angular-auth-oidc-client package's latest (v18) version. The situation I have to solve is the following:

Authenticate against our main Identity Provider
Get the region data from the token
Authenticate agains an other Identity Provider, which authority will be dynamically created from the previous region data
Start the app if both of them done

If I were to know the region beforehand, I might able to use the package's baked in .checkAuthMultiple() call, but as the second config is not there before authentication I have no clue how to add it.
Any help appreciated!
